# Как найти точку пересечение "ленты" с прямой?

Tags: 3d, геометрия

Есть поверхность (синяя "лента" на рисунке), которая задана двумя ломаными в пространстве, количество точек в каждой ломаной одинаково, между каждой i-точкой ломаных можно провести прямую.

Прямая (красным цветом на рисунке ниже), строго вертикальна (верхняя и нижняя точки имеют одинаковые (x,y) координаты).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как найти точку пересечения поверхности с прямой?

PS: если точек пересечений несколько, то нужно взять только первую.

Comment: Плоская поверхность задается 3 точками. Неплоская поверхность не может быть однозначна задана 2 ломаными линиями ..

Comment: @Kromster там говорится, что поверхность задается двумя прямыми. а эти прямые задаются точками i

Comment: В задаче недостаточно условий, чтобы дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: @Kromster, почему? Чего не хватает?

Comment: если задачу решить абстрактно, то нужно будет посчитать  уравнения плоскости, проходящей через две прямые, то есть  матрицу 3 на 3, определить, определить из этого уравнение в абстрактном виде. потом составить уравнение желтоф прямов вида Ax + By + z0 = 0. составить систему уравнений и вывести абстактную формулу. потом подставить числа(координаты) в константы и вычислить точку.   а у вас только абстактные данные

Comment: Повторяю еще раз, плоскость задается 3 точками. Если у вас 4 точки - то однозначно плоскость вывести нельзя, не говоря уже о 2n точках. Если же у вас не плоскость, а лента из пар точек и линия проходит всегда между точками (а не снаружи), то это и есть доп.условие, и такую задачу уже решают иначе

Comment: @Kromster, посмотрите на рисунок, там явно показано, что между каждой i точкой ломаных проходит прямая, т.е. получается лента из четырехугольников в пространстве.

Comment: @Kromster плоскость можно задать как 3 точками, так и 4 при условии, что эти прямые пересекаются или параллельные. то есть у него 4 точки должно создать 2 параллельные прямые иначе задача не решаема

Comment: Четырехугольник в общем случае не является плоскостью. Плоскостями являются только треугольники. Разбивайте вашу "ленту" на треугольники (и обратите внимание, что 4-угольник можно разбить на 3-угольники 2 разными способами и они дадут разные решения) и смотрите пересечения по треугольникам. Альтернативно, интерполируйте положение точки пересечения в 4-угольнике -  но это другой способ. Итого - 3 варианта. Условий для выбора 1 из них - недостаточно. **Если вы опишите исходную задачу - решения может быть определить проще.**

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, плоскость можно задать несколькими способами, в том числе по 3 точкам (по их координатам). Если ломаные заданы координатами точек, то в принципе этого достаточно для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Разбиваете "ленту" на треугольники, в порядки, видимо, таком:

1. a1,a2,a3... это точки левой кривой
2. b1,b2,b3... это точки правой прямой
3. (a1,a2,b1),(a1,b1,b2) и т.д. получающиеся треугольники

И далее ищите точку пересечения этих треугольников с заданной прямой.

Как найти пересечение треугольника и отрезка можно посмотреть, например, [тут](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/intersect/linefacet3d.php)

Comment: Дополнительно вы можете использовать OpenGL Mathematics ([GML](http://example.com)). По каждому из треугольников пройтись [алгоритмом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) Моллера - Трумбора (возвращает расстояния от начала луча до точки пересечения с треугольником).